How to understand “help students find jobs” in this case

Article B (184 words):
Are you a Harry Potter fan? Would you like to go to Hogwarts to study magic? Here comes the good news! You could study magic at the University of Exeter. Starting in September 2024, the British university will offer a one-year course in magic-the first of its kind in the UK.
Students will be able to study history, literature and philosophy during the year. Although they won't learn magic spells, they can take courses on things like dragons in literature and art and the legend of King Arthur.
Emily, a teacher at the university, is leading the course. She says that more and more people are interested in magic. “The study of magic is growing because people are looking for new ways to think about our relationships with the natural world,” she adds. There has been a lot of interest in the course and the university has already got more than 100 inquiries.
According to the university, the course will help students develop skills including creative thinking and lifelong learning. It says this course will help students find jobs in schools, museums, libraries and more.
Questions:

What can we learn from the last paragraph?
A. Why the university will start the course.
B. How the students will choose the course.
C. Where the students will work after university.
D. What skills the students need to take the course.


If “help students find jobs” here means that the university will provide students with the listed jobs, or recommend/appoint to these positions, then C is correct. However, “According to the university” tells me that A is correct.
Which one is more suitable?

The course will not actively get students jobs. What they learn will build creative skills useful in work, or in landing work. (You don't have to believe that opinion, but just accept it as what the article says.) The hack in standardized tests is never to read into the text what it does not specify. Where they will work is not mentioned.

No, it doesn't say and we don't know if the university will provide students with jobs. The course (skills learned in it) will. And there are no listed jobs, only locations. No leaps in logic will work for you here.

This looks to me like a "homework" question, which the OP has just passed straight over to ELL without making any effort to answer it himself.

@FumbleFingers I apologize for my rudeness. This question comes from a quiz four hours ago. I chose A, but the answer is B, and I cannot understand it. I placed my understanding  (why A) and the teacher's opinion (why C) in the question and sought advice here

The "quiz" is stupid. Don't waste your time on it. None of the four "multiple choice" options are meaningfully answered by the highlighted text, and imho How the students will choose the course isn't a meaningful concept here anyway. One student might choose this (presumably, fictitious) course enthusiastically (because it's what they always wanted to study). Another student might make the choice in consultation with his parents (because they'll be paying for it, so he needs their agreement). Another might choose it foolishly (believing it exists, when in fact there is no such course).

It's the skills that will help them find jobs. [three exclamation points] :)

I’m voting to close this question because this is clearly a homework question and no effort is shown and no explanation is given by the OP.

Answer A is correct.
Help students find jobs in this context likely does not mean that the university will directly place students or assist in finding jobs for them. Instead, this is being used abstractly. It means that the knowledge and skills gained will help students find jobs. In other words, students will learn new things that they can use in a future job. This could also be phrased as The course will teach students skills they can use in their careers.
Moreover, the answer C says:

We learn ... where the students will work after university.

Even if the course was directly placing students in jobs, the paragraph doesn't tell us what those jobs are or where the students will be working. Therefore, this cannot be the correct answer.
